# Pentaho reports localization into not supported languages

Tags: python-2.7, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am from Slovakia, I wouldn't be surprised if most of you haven't heard about it.

However, that causes me a troubles when it comes to reports. We need to have 3 (soon 4) language versions of each report: Slovak is main language, than, Polish and English.

Since pentaho does not support Polish nor Slovak, it is really pain for me to keep these localized.

**What I do is:**

1. Create report in Slovak language
2. Write down all phrases from report
3. Send phrases to one of our partners to translate
4. Create its copy in either pl/en directory
5. Open it in Report Designer and edit every phrase accordingly
6. Save as another language version

As you can imagine, the process is very time consuming, and error prone. Plus, every time I add new parameter to report or change its data source (which is BeanShell script), I need to do it in 3 separated files. As a result of this, language mutations are usually out of date, way behind main language version.

I have tried to automate it with OneSky and did a python script that does 2 stages:

**Stage 1 (extract and upload):**

1. Change `*.prpt` files sufix to `*.zip`
2. Extract phrases from files: `~/datadefinition.xml`, `~/layout.xml`, `~/styles.xml`, `~/datasources/inline-ds.xml`
3. Put those phrases into *.po file
4. Export `*.po` file into OneSky

**Stage 2 (download and import):**

5. Change `*.prpt` files sufix to `*.zip`
6. Download translated *.po file from OneSky
7. Run through `~/datadefinition.xml`, `~/layout.xml`, `~/styles.xml`, `~/datasources/inline-ds.xml` files and replace original phrases by translated

While this aproach works fine, it doe not translate everything. There are still flaws of this process. I need to go through it every time I do even slightest change in data source of report or fix small mistakes. Even if I just do a small six in SQL code, I need to do it in 3 files. That of course increases chance to mistake be made.

Soo, I was wondering, how are you guys solving this issue with translating of your reports?

Answer (score 0):

I will share very simple method which we are following.

```
1)create a properties file with key value format for each language for resource labels(for static values)
2)put it into resources folder(report-designer/resources/)
3)Based on the parameter you can specify which properties file to select and you can specify keys into value field so that it can understand which value to display in which language.
4)if you need to convert the data which are coming from database,you have to design data warehouse specify all the mappings,accordingly it can fetch the data.
5)For converting dates and currency symbols or number format you can use inbuilt functions which can handle all this things,i am using mysql and mysql has translation functions which can handle all such things.
```

it is difficult to explain entire process here, but if you can get and idea from this it can be useful to you.